# Duplicate row if: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, plsql

I got these three tables s,a and p. a and s got 1:1 relation. But a to p got 1:x relation.
My current query is only build for 1:0 or 1:1 relation.
Currently I'm getting: "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row." If there's more than one resource_id for an activity_no

So how do I redo my query so If there's two or more resource_id for an activity_id I want to duplicate the selected row two or more times depending on how many resource_id there is for an activity_no?

I've been looking on: [Oracle, insert multirows from subquery with more than one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740749/oracle-insert-multirows-from-subquery-with-more-than-one-row) but It doesn't work.

```
    select s.sub_project_id,  
           a.activity_no,
           (select p.resource_id
            from p
            where p.project_id = 'PROPSTOT'
            and p.activity_seq = a.activity_seq,                                     
from s,
     a
where s.sub_project_id = a.sub_project_id
      and s.project_id = 'PROPSTOT' 
      and a.project_id = 'PROPSTOT'
```

Comment: how are the tables related ? on project_id?

Comment: sorry for the confusion but AN100 should be changed to PROPSTOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what exactly you are trying to do but from your description it sounds you simly want a join:

```
select s.sub_project_id,  
       a.activity_no,
       p.resource_id
from s 
   join a on s.sub_project_id = a.sub_project_id and a.project_id = s.project_id
   left outer join p on p.activity_seq = a.activity_seq
where s.project_id = 'PROPSTOT'
```

Comment: Not all activity_no have a resource_id. Thats why I've a seperate select query for it. If else the query ignores rows without resource_id. Check my updated OP, ANS100 is edited to PROPSTOT.

Comment: @JohnStokes: then you want an outer join.

Comment: @JohnStokes: then you are not running the query from my answer. That one can **not** produce an ORA-01427.

Comment: Nevermind removed my subquery for p.resource_id and It worked!

Answer (score 2):

Try joining to the table in the query, like so:

```
select s.sub_project_id,  
       a.activity_no,
       p.resource_id
from s
join a on s.sub_project_id = a.sub_project_id and a.project_id = 'PROPSTOT'
left join p on p.project_id = 'PROPSTOT' and p.activity_seq = a.activity_seq
where s.project_id = 'PROPSTOT'
```

Comment: Not all activity_no have a resource_id. Thats why I've a seperate select query for it. If else the query ignores rows without resource_id. Check my updated OP, ANS100 is edited to PROPSTOT.